# kdevelop keeps "forgetting" launch configuration

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, kdevelop

I'm running kdevelop 4 under ubuntu 10.4. Everything runs fine, except that when I add a launch configuration, the configuration is gone after I've run my project once. The same goes for configuring keyboard shortcuts (except that in this case the changes i made work for just a few seconds). I've run kdevelop 4 from a console to check if some useful information is printed when I do one of the actions mentioned above, but all I got was this:

couldn't lock local file
couldn't lock local file
couldn't lock local file

Any ideas?

Comment: this question would fit better in [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: @nebukadnezzar, I often see questions about IDEs and I think they're appropriate for a programmer's Q&A site.  (See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kdevelop)

Comment: @Kirk Woll, Yes I know, but the question sounds much more like a userland problem to me.